# mail header "from" domain is automatically replaced by server's domain, why?

Tags: email, server, smtp

The mail header "from" domain of any mail sent to our company's server is replaced by server's domain.

For example:

example@gmail.com send an email to our server(company.com). We see the sender of this email is example@company.com.

I do not know the reason. Please help me. Thanks!

Two examples:

163:

```
From example@company.com  Wed Dec 21 21:47:26 2016 
Return-Path: <example@company.com> 
Received: from m13-141.163.com (m13-141.163.com [220.181.13.141]) 
    by company.com (8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.1ubuntu1) with ESMTP id uBLDlPiQ013409 
    for <xxx@company.com>; Wed, 21 Dec 2016 21:47:26 +0800 
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=163.com; 
    s=s110527; h=Date:From:Subject:MIME-Version:Message-ID; bh=hpaD0 
    qA4I59smafOVhBxwFe3a15FCNfA2uxigC6sgOY=; b=JdNTQe6QHM1TCcgvPCHtw 
    0Lkr1iMuJpydrsSpywGH8QnwV0hMucgh0IO+jg4THKW+2hr/IaVbQJoJabx2W/Mr 
    nQ2YWwc7ECDVaFqU9HJJygtqcrP3d2cp3qBbGlq/YVUUkXidTeX52kQStnULVBzk 
    FEJFuAYeRA/4XZyeo5LxNM= 
Received: from example$163.com ( [192.198.95.71, 54.215.2.217, 10.144.1.72] ) 
by ajax-webmail-wmsvr141 (Coremail) ; Wed, 21 Dec 2016 21:46:07 +0800 (CST) 
X-Originating-IP: [192.198.95.71, 54.215.2.217, 10.144.1.72] 
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2016 21:46:07 +0800 (CST) 
From: "example" <example@company.com> 
To: "xxx@company.com" <xxx@company.com> 
Subject: aaaaa 
X-Priority: 3 
X-Mailer: Coremail Webmail Server Version SP_ntes V3.5 build 
20160729(86883.8884) Copyright (c) 2002-2016 www.mailtech.cn 163com 
X-CM-CTRLDATA: RB7qyGZvb3Rlcl9odG09MjcyNTo1Ng== 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_12111914_355555859.1482327967157" 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Message-ID: <7e744d1.2de269.15921a1c5b6.Coremail.xysmlx@163.com> 
X-Coremail-Locale: zh_CN 
X-CM-TRANSID:jcGowACXpqKfh1pYSOaiAA--.29831W 
X-CM-SenderInfo: p01vzzr06rljoofrz/1tbiNQ1HvlSIRLiDogABsB 
X-Coremail-Antispam: 1U5529EdanIXcx71UUUUU7vcSsGvfC2KfnxnUU== 
Status: RO 
X-UID: 336                                                   
Content-Length: 4432
```

gmail:

```
From example@company.com  Wed Dec 21 22:52:39 2016 
Return-Path: <example@company.com> 
Received: from mail-ua0-f178.google.com (mail-ua0-f178.google.com [209.85.217.178]) 
    by company.com (8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.1ubuntu1) with ESMTP id uBLEqbPm019461 
    for <xxx@company.com>; Wed, 21 Dec 2016 22:52:38 +0800 
Received: by mail-ua0-f178.google.com with SMTP id 2so79983525uax.2 
       for <xxx@company.com>; Wed, 21 Dec 2016 06:52:00 -0800 (PST) 
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; 
       d=gmail.com; s=20161025; 
       h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to; 
       bh=+fBXgxbVSyjlxMpSNMOsZLbhE2bqAQI97mJviWO7ebE=; 
       b=l1SM9poejQhkOB7y725tK1K8oCsbxSENpl+po0nU+AHzyNE0BguFHgLLrFMj7vnuPG 
        ARR0mhWhVow3Pikzeq+IrymrsbnEqyOwgehR/ztTYDY8TPfpghK3O7eRPr9XVhC8oFs+ 
        Il9rCu324IljhOstd/5cWhGkwhA/m2F1bLUoxYw0O18GLVE85uQnH7PZe04W21vPLDVq 
        fuJlrbNFSo4Fxbe626IaS/1CVIUrs5Wkz1YExfa7pADbiqc3RNrEErBrk4FfWRPdHN/y 
        7z7PxqpHvBs+SG2IMx5eCRA5zdsczQvNXHIy3yIHvwkeydYi77PPzR8qUZ2pSfomzmKu 
        LKCg== 
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; 
       d=1e100.net; s=20161025; 
       h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to; 
       bh=+fBXgxbVSyjlxMpSNMOsZLbhE2bqAQI97mJviWO7ebE=; 
       b=CzacaxE4CvL4uxlG4qUkbEm+vAiix3+UR+I7D0xechpMyOGoGrjE/rVfOXl/Zk+8Rr 
        +F4xjJ+kTd7jv1C5d1NGk7CtjMl8mZpUk2bE7WesYV8PryUbY7b6mHpB7XjL3J3AD90o 
        UVPpyX9vjeVJ89E03a1rg05yILGEHWh/E3+bByw68HPxdyCss2I0Tri98030QBWRHasj 
        7BX6qswHzpo2+87yvRpcsBqoSoKgz4L7ydPMt+zXCmxN2VCqw5MX6vLyzuaOIyWR6RFd 
        Uda7z9lqKw8bOo1ntxaMSTwiHmRWZyWtarvB/1MxPRySsJDIc+4tw1YLbfBNNYiWf3C8 
        /SMQ== 
X-Gm-Message-State: AIkVDXKc6Fge9ySWKwRQDYsVUzsuNqgZ9VBci7aM/TEGB915XFQonbYpgBCqBzht712z1QTbDXlrek9X6dKWfA== 
X-Received: by 10.176.85.139 with SMTP id v11mr632414uaa.7.1482331912496; Wed, 
21 Dec 2016 06:51:52 -0800 (PST) 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Received: by 10.176.16.145 with HTTP; Wed, 21 Dec 2016 06:51:12 -0800 (PST) 
From: example <example@company.com> 
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2016 22:51:12 +0800 
Message-ID: <CAO+bwXcoowGtdtZBsQB44K27gUtCJEbpuRKpPj=w66YDQE828g@mail.gmail.com> 
Subject: fdasfdasfdasdasffdas 
To: xxx@company.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=f403045e286e156bca05442c4b0d 
X-UID: 340                                                   
Status: RO 
Content-Length: 2500
```

Comment: Do you have root access to `company.com` server?

Comment: Of course, I have the root access.

Comment: This question have been solved. Thanks! [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/822184/mail-header-from-domain-is-automatically-replaced-by-servers-domain-why/822194#822194)